# Error updating MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update some fields in a table in my database but it always returns error. I think it's some syntax error...

```
$idInscrito = (isset($_GET["id"])) ? $_GET["id"] : "1";

$nota_equipe = $_POST["nota_equipe"];
$nota_proposta_de_valor = $_POST["nota_proposta_de_valor"];
$nota_diferenciacao = $_POST["nota_diferenciacao"];
$nota_escalabilidade = $_POST["nota_escalabilidade"];
$nota_etapas_de_desenvolvimento = $_POST["nota_etapas_de_desenvolvimento"];
$nota_canais_de_comercializacao = $_POST["nota_canais_de_comercializacao"];
$nota_relevancia_mercado = $_POST["nota_relevancia_mercado"];
$nota_alinhamento_economia = $_POST["nota_alinhamento_economia"];
$nota_publico_alvo = $_POST["nota_publico_alvo"];
$nota_concorrentes = $_POST["nota_concorrentes"];
$nota_formas_de_consumo = $_POST["nota_formas_de_consumo"];
$nota_valores_de_investimentos = $_POST["nota_valores_de_investimentos"];
$nota_projecao_de_receitas = $_POST["nota_projecao_de_receitas"];

$sql = "UPDATE tb_inscricoes SET (data, nota_equipe, nota_proposta_de_valor, nota_diferenciacao, nota_escalabilidade, nota_etapas_de_desenvolvimento, nota_canais_de_comercializacao, nota_relevancia_mercado, nota_alinhamento_economia, nota_publico_alvo, nota_concorrentes, nota_formas_de_consumo, nota_valores_de_investimentos, nota_projecao_de_receitas) VALUES (now(), '$nota_equipe', '$nota_proposta_de_valor', '$nota_diferenciacao', '$nota_escalabilidade', '$nota_etapas_de_desenvolvimento', '$nota_canais_de_comercializacao', '$nota_relevancia_mercado', '$nota_alinhamento_economia', '$nota_publico_alvo', '$nota_concorrentes', '$nota_formas_de_consumo', '$nota_valores_de_investimentos', '$nota_projecao_de_receitas') WHERE id=$idInscrito";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Please post your questions in English

Comment: Google translator to the rescue!

Comment: SQL injections occur in every language.

Comment: The problem with using Google Translate like this is that the OP may not understand any comments or, indeed, the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You were incorrectly using the `INSERT` syntax for doing an `UPDATE` in MySQL.  Try this code instead:

Você incorretamente estavam usando a sintaxe INSERT para fazer um UPDATE em MySQL. Tente este código em vez disso:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tb_inscricoes SET data = 'now()', nota_equipe = '$nota_equipe', nota_proposta_de_valor = '$nota_proposta_de_valor', nota_diferenciacao = '$nota_diferenciacao', nota_escalabilidade = '$nota_escalabilidade', nota_etapas_de_desenvolvimento = '$nota_etapas_de_desenvolvimento', nota_canais_de_comercializacao = '$nota_canais_de_comercializacao', nota_relevancia_mercado = '$nota_relevancia_mercado', nota_alinhamento_economia = '$nota_alinhamento_economia', nota_publico_alvo = '$nota_publico_alvo', nota_concorrentes = '$nota_concorrentes', nota_formas_de_consumo = '$nota_formas_de_consumo', nota_valores_de_investimentos = '$nota_valores_de_investimentos', nota_projecao_de_receitas = '$nota_projecao_de_receitas') WHERE id=$idInscrito";
```

Comment: I love Portugúese! kkkk

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim, but its not working :(